# How to correctly parse this bad html in Nokogiri?

Tags: html, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to parse this HTML with Nokogiri:

```
<div class="times">
<span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 ">&lrm;</span><!--  -->16:45&lrm;</span>
<span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 "> &nbsp;&lrm;</span><!--  -->19:30&lrm;</span> 
<span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 "> &nbsp;&lrm;</span><!--  -->22:10&lrm;</span>
</div>
```

I only want to get the times, inserted in an array.

I set up a gsub like this:

```
 block.css('div.times span').text.gsub(" ","").gsub("&nbsp","")
```

But then I end up with a single string and I'm kind of stuck. Is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you could do is to leave the whitespace in the string, and then use [`String#split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-split) to convert it to an array:

```
block.css('div.times span').text.gsub("&nbsp","").split(' ')
```

In this case you might need to strip out the left-to-right markers as well, and I don’t think you need to replace the non-breaking spaces, so you could try this:

```
block.css('div.times span').text.gsub("\u200e", '').split(' ')
```

(`\u200e` is the left-to-right marker).

An alternative with Nokogiri is to use [xpath](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-xpath) instead of CSS, which will enable you to select just the text nodes you want directly, then use `map` to convert to an array of strings:

```
block.xpath('//div[@class="times"]/span/text()').map(&:text)
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll look up the XCode documentation, seems definitely more flexible than parsing using the HTML method. The CSS method you suggested, however, sometimes produces an array with an empty item, such as ["‎17:15‎‎", "‎20:00‎", "‎", "‎22:40"]. I guess it's because of the empty space between the <-- -->?

Comment: I can’t reproduce the extra empty item with the sample from the question. Can you give an example of a line where it happens?

Comment: Sure, sorry for the delay in answering.     <div class="times"><span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 ">‎</span><!--  -->19:10‎</span><span style="color:"><span style="padding:0 "> &nbsp;‎</span><!--  -->22:10‎</span></div> gives ["‎19:10‎‎", "‎22:10‎", ""] as a result of the css processing..

Comment: @Firebringer I think it’s the `&lrm;`s in your html that’s causing the problems, have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest is probably:

```
block.at('div.times').text.scan /\d{2}:\d{2}/
```

Comment: Pretty handy indeed. Thanks for the reply :)